# Sites background image works perfect on PC but they don't appear on mobile devices

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css, responsive-design

I am facing an interesting issue with my current project site. The background images used on **HERO AREA , TESTIMONIAL AREA , CONTACT AREA** loads perfect on PC. But those background images don't load / Appear on mobile devices.

I am unable to find out the cause behind this problem.
Here is the live link of my project: http://themebite.github.io/demo/effacy/

How can i load those background images on mobile as perfectly as they loads on PC.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use the media queries to set CSS properties for example `background-size: 100% 100%;` This will solve your problem

```
.static-bg {
    background: transparent url("../img/bg/hero-bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```